# Finding min value in a dictionary in O(1) time Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, time-complexity, big-o

I need a way to find the minimum value in a dictionary full of Node objects in O(1) time, or really any sublinear time, if possible.

Here's an example of what I'd need:

```
'''
 Nodes have 4 attributes: 
  - stack
  - backwards
  - forwards
  - total_score
'''
dict = {str(Node1.stack): Node1, 
        str(Node2.stack): Node2, ... } # note that keys are the stacks as strings

key, smallest = min(frontier.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1].total_score)
( ^^^ something better than this! ^^^ )
```

The last line above (key, smallest ... ) is what I have so far. It works fine, but it's too slow. I read online that the min() function takes O(n) time. I have a lot of Nodes to process, so something faster would be amazing.

*edit* Should have mentioned before, but this is running inside an A* algorithm - frontier is updated dynamically. The operations I need to be able to do are:

1. Find minimum in O(1), or at least < O(n)
2. Update values of specific elements quickly
3. Access attributes easily

Comment: You will probably need to maintain a sorted sequence (list) of objects in the dictionary alongside the dictionary itself. You can probably wrap that up into your own new subclass of dict that overrides the insert and remove methods to maintain the list at the same time the dict itself is modified.

Comment: Does the insertion time matter as well? If it does not, keep a sorted list of node values. The first element of the list [O(1)!] is the smallest one.

Comment: @DYZ Insertion time doesn't matter, but unfortunately I don't have the list of nodes ahead of time. I am using this inside an A* algorithm, and the Nodes in the frontier are dynamically generated. I'd have to resort every time which kinda defeats the purpose imo.

Comment: Making a subclass of [MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) is probably the way to go.

Comment: You don't need them ahead of time if you use your own class for the dictionary. You build the sorted list as the data is added to the dict.

Comment: You can store the nodes, as they arrive, in a binary tree, it is even better than a list: insertion time O(log N), min lookup time O(1).

Comment: You can keep an auxiliary heap of you have to account for insertion and deletion, if it can only grow, you can just keep track of the minimum seperately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible to get the min value from a dictionary in O(1) time because you have to check every value. However, you can do a fast lookup if you store your data in a heap or a sorted tree, where the data is sorted by value. Trees generally give you insertion and search times of O(log n).

If you literally only need the min value of your data and you don't ever need to look up other values, you could just create a `minValue` variable that you keep updated every time you insert or remove items.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah just storing a value would be perfectly fine haha. It's always the simple things :)

Comment: The min value suggestion of the second paragraph doesn't work if you update values - suppose you update or remove the current min by increasing it's value.  How do you find the new min in O(1)?  It's possible that the data structure OP is looking for is a _priority heap_ - see _heapq_.  Depends on whether you need to look up arbitrary elements or only the minimum.

Comment: You are correct, if OP ever needs to update or remove existing values, then updating the min is O(n) for a dictionary. If it's important to be fast in those cases, then yeah a heap is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get the smallest value in a dictionary in O(1), it will take O(n).

You can also do one thing while you are adding the elements in the dictionary you can maintain the minimum value and check at the moment itself.

Answer (score 0):

in most cases, you can "create" an environment to run min/max/remove... at O(1) speed.  for example, they are O(1) in a constant size list...